# Unable to upload image correctly to SharePoint online using Graph API from within Graph Explorer (image corrupted but text file works)

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, graph-explorer

I struggling to upload an image to SharePoint online using Graph API from within Graph Explorer. I have managed to upload text file which uploads correctly but when attempting image its corrupted.

I am pushing image Base64 in body and it will create image to SharePoint online but corrupted/unable to open. I also tried to include header Content-Type image/png

[image: Upload snippet from Graph Explorer]

Image in SharePoint:

[image: Image view in SharePoint]

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Can you share your code, it will be easier to point out what's wrong!

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert from base64 to binary:

```
Convert.FromBase64String(base64Image);    
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
request.AddHeader("Content-Length", binaryImage.Length);
request.AddParameter("application/octet-stream", binaryImage, 
ParameterType.RequestBody);
```